# How to display difficult-model view in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view

I have such db schema:

```
Tables:
COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS
DES_TEXTS
MANUFACTURERS
MODELS
```

And such relationships:

```
COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS has_many MODELS
DES_TEXTS has_many COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS
MANUFACTURERS has_many MODELS
```

In rails model all relations and other "things" are written.

And when i select manufactures, I get all it's models. But now I want in these models to select data from COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS (sure all table relations id's must be equal), and then when select data from COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS i want to fetch data from DES_TEXTS and display it.

How can i do this? what change in controllers, views? (I were using standart scaffolds)

now i have such view to view models from manufacturer:

```
  - @manufacturer.models.each do |model|
    %tr
      %p
        mod_id
        %td= model.MOD_ID
      %p
        MOD_PCON_START
        %td= model.MOD_PCON_START
      %p
        MOD_PCON_END
        %td= model.MOD_PCON_END
      = link_to 'Show model', model
```

and i want to add something like this:

```
  - @manufacturer.models.each do |model|
    %tr
      %p
        ...
        %td= model.country_des.des_text.FIELD  - something like this)
      = link_to 'Show model', model
```

models files:

```
class CountryDesignation < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS"
    set_primary_key :CDS_ID
    belongs_to :des_text
    belongs_to :language
    has_many :models
end

class DesText < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "DES_TEXTS"
    set_primary_key :TEX_ID
    has_many :country_designation
    has_many :designation
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "MODELS"
    set_primary_key :MOD_ID
    belongs_to :manufacturer
    belongs_to :country_designation
    has_many :types
end



dump:
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended to check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120418164608) do

  create_table "COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS", :primary_key => "CDS_ID", :force => true do |t|
    t.binary   "CDS_CTM"
    t.integer  "CDS_LNG_ID"
    t.integer  "CDS_TEX_ID"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "DESIGNATIONS", :primary_key => "DES_ID", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "DES_LNG_ID"
    t.integer  "DES_TEX_ID"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "DES_TEXTS", :primary_key => "TEX_ID", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "TEX_TEXT"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "LANGUAGES", :primary_key => "LNG_ID", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "LNG_DES_ID"
    t.string   "LNG_ISO2"
    t.string   "LNG_CODEPAGE"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "MANUFACTURERS", :primary_key => "MFA_ID", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "MFA_PC_MFC"
    t.integer  "MFA_CV_MFC"
    t.integer  "MFA_AXL_MFC"
    t.integer  "MFA_ENG_MFC"
    t.integer  "MFA_ENG_TYP"
    t.string   "MFA_MFC_CODE"
    t.string   "MFA_BRAND"
    t.integer  "MFA_MF_NR"
    t.binary   "MFA_PC_CTM"
    t.binary   "MFA_CV_CTM"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "MODELS", :primary_key => "MOD_ID", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "MOD_MFA_ID"
    t.integer  "MOD_CDS_ID"
    t.integer  "MOD_PCON_START"
    t.integer  "MOD_PCON_END"
    t.integer  "MOD_PC"
    t.integer  "MOD_CV"
    t.integer  "MOD_AXL"
    t.binary   "MOD_PC_CTM"
    t.binary   "MOD_CV_CTM"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "TYPES", :primary_key => "TYP_ID", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "TYP_CDS_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_MMT_CDS_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_MOD_ID"
    t.binary   "TYP_CTM"
    t.binary   "TYP_LA_CTM"
    t.integer  "TYP_SORT"
    t.integer  "TYP_PCON_START"
    t.integer  "TYP_PCON_END"
    t.integer  "TYP_KW_FROM"
    t.integer  "TYP_KW_UPTO"
    t.integer  "TYP_HP_FROM"
    t.integer  "TYP_HP_UPTO"
    t.integer  "TYP_CCM"
    t.integer  "TYP_CYLINDERS"
    t.integer  "TYP_DOORS"
    t.integer  "TYP_TANK"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_VOLTAGE_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_ABS_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_ASR_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_ENGINE_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_BRAKE_TYPE_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_BRAKE_SYST_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_FUEL_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_CATALYST_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_BODY_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_STEERING_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_STEERING_SIDE_DES_ID"
    t.float    "TYP_MAX_WEIGHT"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_MODEL_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_AXLE_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_CCM_TAX"
    t.float    "TYP_LITRES"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_DRIVE_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_TRANS_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_KV_FUEL_SUPPLY_DES_ID"
    t.integer  "TYP_VALVES"
    t.integer  "TYP_RT_EXISTS"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "carts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "amount"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "credit_cards", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.string   "number"
    t.string   "nameOfCard"
    t.date     "expiryDate"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "currencies", :force => true do |t|
    t.float    "currencyvalue"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "customer_sessions", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "customers", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "crypted_password"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.string   "persistence_token"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "skype"
    t.integer  "ICQ"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "street"
    t.string   "building"
    t.integer  "room"
    t.string   "addressNote"
    t.string   "dateOfReg"
    t.integer  "custGroup_id"
    t.float    "totalBuy"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "order_statuses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "statusname"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "orders", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "basket_id"
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.integer  "shipping_id"
    t.integer  "paymentmethod_id"
    t.integer  "orderstatus_id"
    t.datetime "dateoforder"
    t.float    "totalcost"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "payment_methods", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "methodname"
    t.boolean  "allowed"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "sellers", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "crypted_password"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.string   "persistence_token"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "skype"
    t.integer  "ICQ"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "dateOfReg"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "shippings", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "shippingname"
    t.float    "shippingcost"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "telephone_operators", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "telephones", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.integer  "operator"
    t.integer  "number"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "virtual_pay_systems", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "virtual_pays", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.string   "number"
    t.integer  "virtualpaysystem_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: Could you add your models instead of the "relations"? If your models would contain the normal stuff (like `class Model; belongs_to country_designation`...), you should normally be able to navigate from `Model` to `CountryDesignation` to `DesText`.

Comment: If my answer does not work for you, it could be that your migrations  are not the right one for the model code we have written. You should then add the schema dump (found in `db/schema.rb`) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written should mostly work, but there is a subtle error in it:

- The [`belongs_to` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association) uses the singular (as in `belongs_to :manufacturer`), but for the [association`has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association), you have to use the plural:

  ```
  class DesText < ActiveRecord::Base
      set_table_name "DES_TEXTS"
      set_primary_key :TEX_ID
      has_many :country_designations
      has_many :designations
  end
  ```
- Please ensure that the relevant keys are set in your tables. Here are the rules for you:

  - Every `has_many` association (see [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association)) needs that the many part has a reference to the one part. In your example: `Model` needs a reference to `CountryDesignation`. Rails thinks that your model table includes a column `country_designation_id` (which it will not find).
  - Similar for `DES_TEXTS` and `COUNTRY_DESIGNATIONS`.

After having corrected that, you should be able to use the following code (only the changed one with the deep access over some objects):

```
- @manufacturer.models.each do |model|
  %tr
    %p
      ...
      %td= model.country_designation.des_text.FIELD
    = link_to 'Show model', model
```

This will show inside a loop for each model of the manufacturer the `des_text` of its `country_designation`.
*But be careful:* This is only an example and will only work, if every model has a country designation and every country designation has a des_text.

It is unfortunate that you use an existing db scheme, it makes a lot of things more difficult. I would give you the following advice here:

- Migrate to a clean state with names rails suspects.
- Test after each migration, if your model conforms to the rules by using the console of Rails. You can start then `rails c` and type there in commands you think should work.
- Your application is a the moment to big and complicated, so I don't think there is a chance to debug it further here ... (sorry, but this is the fourth time I add to my answer, and it looks more like a Rails tutorial now)

Comment: ok, thank, but what i asked is how to use this in a view? how display this in view (manufacturer->model and then for model select from country and then des_text)?

Comment: undefined method `    ` for nil:NilClass

Comment: note! this is done for manufacturer show view, and controller

Comment: in this db, all has all )) but i still get errors, and didn't know how to solve it